# Get users who are in a role

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I have written a `ViewModel` `RoleUsers` and I would like to gather all `Users` who are a member of a `Role` with `Name = string id`.

I know I cannot use `Roles.GetUsersInRole` with Identity. I have thought about using an instance of `ApplicationDbContext` with `_db.Users.Where()` but I'm not sure how to use this method, as the description isn't too clear.

How can I find all `users` with `role = string id`?

**EDIT** Currently, I am trying to make a `new RoleUsers{}` in the Details method of the controller.

```
RoleUsers roleUsers = new RoleUsers
{
    Role = new Role(id),
    Users = ...
}
```

What should I replace the dots with?
I was thinking about using `userManager` here?

**EDIT2**: I have solved quite a bit so far.

```
var roleId = roleManager.FindByName(id);

   var roleUsers = new RoleUsers
   {
       Role = new Role(id),
       Users = _db.Users.Where(x => x.Roles.Select(y => roleId.Name).Contains(id)).ToList()
   };
```

Now I am getting **all** users at all, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: [RoleManager.Roles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613189(v=vs.108).aspx) is likely to be useful.

Comment: Does that mean having to enable `roleManager` in `web.config`? Because then I would break other functionality.

Comment: No. It's not tied to that. `RoleManager` is a class. You may have your own subclass of it already, or you may be using the built in one. Create a new ASP.NET 2013 project with Individual Accounts and you'll see it scaffolds out one for you.

Comment: I have edited my question, after you helped me on my way quite a bit! I now understand Identity/MemberShip better. :)

Comment: I have no idea what you want `RoleUsers` for. There is a `RoleManager` somewhere in your application. You just need to get an instance of that and then access the `Roles` property of it.

Comment: I want to use the ViewModel to base my view on that, so I can show a list of users who are belonging to that role.
So I want to have one model that contains the role and the users who are in that role.

Comment: Okay. Well still, you need to get an instance of either `UserManager` or `RoleManager` in your controller, then populate your view models based on that.

Comment: That's what I understand, but I don't feel how I should collect all the Users who belong to a Role. Should I use  `userManager.Users.Where()` and if so, how should I use `Write()`, as that is unclear to me?

Comment: `.Where()` is a Linq extension method that takes a lambda and expected the lambda to return a boolean. So let's say the details page is for role `roleName`. `var usersInRole = userManager.Users.Where(u => /* check to see if u is in role here */ );`

Comment: What Authentication Scheme are you using?  Form Authentication, Simple Membership or the default (for MVC 5) Asp.Net Identity (1 or 2)?

Comment: I am using MVC5 and EF6, not sure which Identity(1/2) I am using, using the out of the box auth.

Comment: Edited question, could you please take another look at it, for me?
@ErikPhilips, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with this piece of code:

```
var roleId = roleManager.FindByName(id);
var roleUsers = new RoleUsers
{
    Role = new Role(id),
    Users = _db.Users.Where(x => x.Roles.Any(y => y.RoleId == roleId.Id)).ToList()
};
```